# How to Convert date format in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

How to convert date format in xslt. I have created application as shown below

### I used xml :

2015-01-06T17:51:01.67+05:30

### My xslt file :

select="format-dateTime(TravellerRequest/RequestDate,'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>

### in html page getting error :

Exception Details: System.Xml.Xsl.XsltException: 'format-dateTime()' is an unknown XSLT function.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I need output like this: 01/06/2015

How to convert the above datetime format into mm/dd/yyyy.

plz guide me.

Thanks,
Ram...

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you working with?

Comment: Hi , i written xslt like this , please help me.
My xslt file :
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:template match="TRSummary">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(TravellerRequest/RequestDate,'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I used xml :

<TRSummary>
 <TravellerRequest> 
  <RequestDate>2015-01-06T17:51:01.67+05:30</RequestDate>  
 </TravellerRequest>
</TRSummary>

Comment: in html page getting error :

Exception Details: System.Xml.Xsl.XsltException: 'format-dateTime()' is an unknown XSLT function.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I need output like this: 01/06/2015

How to convert the above datetime format into mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: You should edit your question with this information, rather than put it in comments. To put code in the question, just copy it in, highlight it, and click the `{}` button to format it as code to make it readable. Alternatively, just put 4 spaces before each line of code (as that is what the `{}` button does). Thank you.

Comment: i tried to edit question that time i got  error message like this please properly format as code. 

please provide above question solution.

Answer (score 3):

`format-dateTime()` is an XSLT 2.0 function. Your error message suggests that you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor. XSLT 1.0 does not recognize dates as such - but you can use string functions to rearrange the date to the required format:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(TravellerRequest/RequestDate, 9, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(TravellerRequest/RequestDate, 6, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(TravellerRequest/RequestDate, 1, 4)"/>
```

---

**Note:**
If you're using a Microsoft processor (as suggested by Martin Honnen), see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: please how can i  use format-dateTime()  for date conversion, please guid me.

Answer (score 0):

The function requires an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime. Based on the message `System.Xml.Xsl.XsltException`, you seem to use a Microsoft XSLT processor, Microsoft only supports XSLT 1.0. So you will need to change your application to use a third party XSLT 2.0 processor or you need to look into using a .NET extension object or function with Microsoft's XSLT processor, to delegate the formatting to .NET code, not to XSLT code.